# Ubuntu 16.04 not showing up 1650x1080 res

Tags: 16.04, screen, display-resolution

I'm completely new to Ubuntu. Im using an all in one Acer z1 621g. The intel graphics baytrail drivers are installed. I've got an acer 21.5 inch led screen but Ubuntu can only detect 1920x1080 and resolutions under 1366x768.

In windows I had 1650x1080 and it was working fine but in Ubuntu I do not have it and the reason why I'm trying to switch to 1650x1080 is that one side of led shows colored lines (which is a led cable issue I will fix later).

I tried to set modes using

```
cvt 1650 1080 60 sudo xrandr --newmode "1650x1080_60.00" bla bla
```

And then

```
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1650x1080_60.00
```

But when I type

```
sudo xrandr -s 1650x1080
```

it says `mode 1650x1080 not found`.

Answer (score 0):

After do this, you should change a file. To do this put in terminal:

```
gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And in the line "Modes ..." put "1650x1080@75" the first element.
The line will be:

```
Modes "1650x1080@75" "..." ...
```

After modificate, save the changes and restart your computer.

Good luck!